# Where should I ask questions that are too "chatty" for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, chat, asking-questions

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is pretty clear; all questions should be specific and answerable, not open ended discussions.

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

So here I am with a burning question that I'd like a broad range of opinions on but I think it'll violate this (quite sensible) policy.

Where should I ask it instead? Or, put differently, where's the best place to ask broad, software development related questions with no definitive answer, that may well generate some informed discussion?

Comment: In one of the chatrooms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious answer here is to go to a related SO [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) room, however, getting a real answer in some rooms (as they are under-trafficked) can be difficult.

If that turns out to be the case, try heading over to a related tag's wiki, and look for other websites specifically for that subject (forums, github project page, etc.), and you may get a better answer.

If all else fails, you *could* try asking the question in a different way, to minimize the amount of 'chattiness' that would ensue. However, note that many questions like that (e.g. "What is the 'best' way to do x") will get closed fast.